# How to convert css to style components for the below style

Tags: html, css, reactjs

I'm trying to convert the below style to styled component.

**My CSS code::**

```
ol.progtrckr {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    list-style-type: none;
    width: 100%;
}
ol.progtrckr li.progtrckr-done::before {
    content: "\2713";
    color: white;
    background-color: yellowgreen;
    height: 1.2em;
    border: none;
    border-radius: 1.2em;
}
ol.progtrckr li.progtrckr-todo::before {
    content: "\039F";
    color: silver;
    background-color: white;
    font-size: 1.5em;
    bottom: -1.6em;
}
```

**My styled components code ::**

```
    const OLStepper = styled.ol`
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    list-style-type: none;
    width: 100%;
    `;
    const LIStepperDone = styled.li`
       &:before {
      content: "\2713";
      color: white;
      background-color: yellowgreen;
      height: 1.2em;
      border: none;
      border-radius: 1.2em;}
    
    `;
    
    const LIStepperTodo = styled.li`
          &:before {
      content: "\039F";
      color: silver;
      background-color: white;
      font-size: 1.5em;
      bottom: -1.6em;
    }
    
    `;
```

**I am using it this say in react::**

```
<ol className="progtrckr" >
    <li className="progtrckr-done">Order Processing</li>
    <li className="progtrckr-done">Pre-Production</li>
    <li className="progtrckr-done">In Production</li>
    <li className="progtrckr-done">Shipped</li>
    <li className="progtrckr-todo">Delivered</li>
    
</ol>
```

I have the above css I want to convert it to styled component.The one I wrote didn't work.Please help me –
Thanks in advance

Comment: Sorry, i can't understand you !

Comment: if you can , explain question

Comment: I have the above css I want to convert it to styled component.The one I wrote didn't work.Please help me

Answer (score 0):

Here's an example of how to correctly use styled components. Reference `[Styled Components Documentation][1]`

```
import React from 'react'
import styled from 'styled-components'

const StyledCounter = styled.div`
  /* ... */
`
const Paragraph = styled.p`
  /* ... */
`
const Button = styled.button`
  /* ... */
`

export default class Counter extends React.Component {
  state = { count: 0 }

  increment = () => this.setState({ count: this.state.count + 1 })
  decrement = () => this.setState({ count: this.state.count - 1 })

  render() {
    return (
      <StyledCounter>
        <Paragraph>{this.state.count}</Paragraph>
        <Button onClick={this.increment}>+</Button>
        <Button onClick={this.decrement}>-</Button>
      </StyledCounter>
    )
  }
}
```

Basically to answer your question, the `<ol></ol>` element in your code becomes `<OLStepper></OLStepper>`. You would repeat this for your other styled components. Hope this pointed you in the right direction.